# Pasar Texto distinto de Spinner a EditText

Tags: java, android

Tengo un Spinner y un EditText consigo que lo que selecciono en el Spinner se pase al EditText pero quiero que se pase otro texto, Pongo un ejemplo.

Selecciono "Acuario (Ene. 20 - Feb. 18)" en mi Spinner y en mi EditText se escribe lo mismo, pero quiero que solamente se escriba lo primero, es decir "Acuario"

Cómo podría hacerlo? Dejo aquí mi código para que veáis como paso el texto de mi Spinner a mi EditText:

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] titulo_zodiaco;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] titulo_zodiaco) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.titulo_zodiaco = titulo_zodiaco;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenspinner);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textspinner);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(titulo_zodiaco[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
    String[] zodiaco = {"Acuario (Ene. 20 - Feb. 18)", "Piscis (Feb. 19 - Marzo 20)", "Aries (Marzo 31 - Abril 19)", "Tauro (Abril 20 - Mayo 20)", "Géminis (Mayo 21 - Junio 20)", "Cáncer (Junio 21 - Julio 22)", "Leo (Julio 23 - Agosto 22)", "Virgo (Agosto 23 - Sep. 22)", "Libra (Sep. 23 - Oct. 22)", "Escorpio (Oct. 23 - Nov. 21)", "Sagitario (Nov. 22 - Dic. 21)", "Capricornio (Dic. 22 - Ene. 19)"};
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.icon_zod_acuario, R.drawable.icon_zod_piscis, R.drawable.icon_zod_aries, R.drawable.icon_zod_tauro, R.drawable.icon_zod_geminis, R.drawable.icon_zod_cancer, R.drawable.icon_zod_leo, R.drawable.icon_zod_virgo, R.drawable.icon_zod_libra, R.drawable.icon_zod_escorpio, R.drawable.icon_zod_sagitario, R.drawable.icon_zod_capricornio};

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerbasico);
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), flags, zodiaco);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String description = zodiaco[position];
        editTextZodiaco.setText(description);
    }


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues pensándolo rápidamente, podrías utilizar SPLIT para la cadena seleccionada y utilizar el espacio de separación entre "Acuario" y "(Ene. 20 - Feb. 18)" como patrón.

En tu código:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String description = zodiaco[position]; // Lo puedes hacer aquí
    editTextZodiaco.setText(description.split(" ")[0]); // o aquí
}
```

Cuando haces el SPLIT, este te devolverá un array y de ese array seleccionas la posición inicial, ya que será en todos los casos de tu array, la palabra que deseas mostrar.

Te dejo la documentación oficial de JAVA.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Me podrías poner un ejemplo en tu respuesta? Gracias @KingRoach

Comment: Gracias por añadirlo, pero haciendo lo que me comentas me sale al revés de lo que quiero hacer, en el Spinner sale la palabra y en el EditText completo @KingRoach

Comment: Perdona, lo había entendido mal, si quieres hacer que en EditText se muestre solo la palabra "Acuario", puedes hacer el SPLIT cuando asignas el string en el EditText, edito la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora sí, perfecto! No sé quien te dio -1, te doy +1 y marco como solucionado, gracias @KingRoach !

Comment: Gracias, un saludo.